# The application of logic to the metaphor of glass half full or half empty

Tags: logic, terminology, semantics

If there is optimistic, pessimistic, and realistic, what would be the most logical way of defining unrealistic?

For example, the optimistic says the glass is half full.
The pessimistic says the glass is half empty.
The realistic says the glass is 50% filled.
But the unrealistic... how would this be best defined?

Comment: "There is no spoon" ?

Comment: The best answer I know is to say the glass is completely full: half water and half air.

Comment: Philosophically when you utter *realistic* you're committed to realism, the opposite usually is idealism (according to Popper), so you can say whatever your ideology favors, if you're an optimistic idealists you can say whatever they say, or you can say *nothing* and continue your meditation if you're a phenomenological yogi, only when you're thirsty then you may grab and drink it...

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Made edits and suggested tags to try to stave off uncharitable closure.

Comment: @DoubleKnot: The glass is half way towards the ideal glass, which is full as part of it's perfection. Thus the existence of a full glass has been proven. Unrealism.. :)

Comment: The unrealistic would simply say a lie because unlike the pessimistic and optimistic There statements can be found true in every scenario not just the glass scenario. But the unrealistic would have to say something that was unrealistic and something that isn't real is a lie. Like if you ask an unrealistic person they would say something like this The glass is full when the water level only reaches half way of the glass in reality.

Answer (score -1):

The unrealistic says the glass is full when its half-full. He's being unrealistically optimistic. If he says the glass is full and has always been full and can never be emptied, then he's an idealist.

He can also say the glass is empty when its half-empty. He's bring unrealistically pessimistic. If he says that there is no glass, that there never has been a glass and nor will there ever be one, then he's a nihilist.

And if he says, the glass has just sprouted wings and flown off. Then he's a fantasist.

Answer (score -1):

#### Short Answer

If you follow the basic rules of introductory logic, a non-realist, someone who is unrealistic, is simply an optimist or pessimist. There's no need to invent new categories.

#### Long Answer

Definitions are flexible. You can define words however you want, however, I'd suggest we look at how language is already used. There are some creative answers here, but I suggest you follow what's already laid out in the logic of the metaphor. None of the answers so far seem to do this.

In this metaphor, note:

1. An optimist focuses on the full half.
2. A pessimist focuses on the empty half.
3. A realist focuses on both the full and empty halves.

Therefore, to negate (3), unrealistic (adj) or non-realist(n), simply negate the sentence.

4. A non-realist does **not** focus on both the full and empty halves.

But, both (1) or (2) qualify, so since they are mutually exclusive, we use either-or:

**C. A non-realist is either an optimist or pessimist.**

Like I said, all of the other answers are acceptable, but sometimes it makes sense to stick to the logical implication inherent in the language.